# Ubuntu internet connection problem

Tags: internet, dns

I installed Ubuntu on my laptop. Here are my internet settings:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.1.17.10  /*this is my IP @ddress*/
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

I cannot connect to internet. I can ping 8.8.8.8 successfully but not any website.

Any help, please? I cannot access the internet this way.

Comment: Can you add the output of `nm-tool` to your question?

Comment: @Mitch: nm-tool says (among other information): ETH typ: Wired, HW is given. The same thing also with eth1

Comment: What does it list for DNS?

Comment: @Mitch: there is no line in the output that mentions DNS

Comment: If there is no DNS, you can't browse the Internet.  Check your DNS settings.

Answer (score 1):

You have no viable route because you haven't specified one. I suggest you change your file to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.1.17.10  
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.1.17.1  
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 10.1.17.1
```

Of course, substitute the address of your router or access point if not 10.1.17.1.

Generally, setting such details is preferred in Network Manager rather than in /etc/network/interfaces.

If you have an interface eth1, it is either a second ethernet card or a wireless interface. Check:

```
iwconfig
```

Does your computer have two ethernet ports? Are you attempting to connect with wired ethernet?

Have you confirmed the gateway and other details by checking the network settings on other connected devices on your network?

Comment: I did what you said, but I can not even ping 8.8.8.8. When I tape route i do not find any gateway either

Comment: Does the fact I have eth1 in addition to eth0 and lo affects my configuration ?

Comment: I can not even ping 8.8.8.8

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is the lack of a gateway. How are you connected to the internet? What is the output of *route*?

Comment: it outputs 3 gateways: 2 of them are marked by * (star, no IP address for them, only Genmask 255.255.255.0 and the other 255.255.0.0), the last one is called dsldevice.lan, Genmask 0.0.0.0, it is the default one)